# How to create a javascript variable from a DOM element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Let say I have the following DOM element on my page:

```
<div id="name">Sharon</div>
```

**Q1:**
Using jQuery, how do I turn the content of #name into a JS variable so I can reuse it in other 
places on the DOM?

**Q2:**
What's the best way to render a JS variable into my HTML using jQuery? Taking it a step further, if I wanted to remove the content of an element then replace it with the variable what's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save "Sharon" in a variable, use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
var content = $('#name').html();
```

To render it somewhere else (replacing anything that was in that HTML tag before):

```
$('#example').html(content);
```

Or, to [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it after any content that's in the #example tag, use

```
$('#example').append(content);
```

Also look at [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** You can just get the HTML with `.html()`:

```
var content = $('#name').html();
```

If you're looking for *only* the text (no styling), then use the `.text()` function instead:

```
var content = $('#name').text();
```

**Q2:** Setting a parameter for the `.html()` function *sets* the HTML of that targeted element:

```
$('#otherName').html('I am the <i>new</i> content');
```

Similarly, if you are only setting the text, replace `.html()` with `.text()` in my code.

Comment: One could also use `$('#name').text()` to just get the innerText of the element (it's equal to `$('#name').html()` in this simple case, but may be different for more complex cases)...

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Blender.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. with `.html()` you just get an string of what is inside the element selected and you can't bind events or stuff like that with with solid JavaScript when you select element with jQuery or jQuery then `.html()`.

When you define a variable to a jQuery selector it's not equal with what you define with solid JavaScript.

```
$('body') == document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
//false
```

using `.html()` will not solve your problem:

```
('body').html() == document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
//false
```

`.html()` gives you an string equals to what's inside the element:

```
$('body').html() == document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.toString()
//true
```

The fact is that jQuery selectors always return an array that contains every element matching the given query event if your query returns one element it will return an array with one element. So with selecting any element of every jQuery selector array you will get an actual DOM element.

```
$('body')[0] == document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```

***Try this in your browser developer tool to see the result! :D***